# HTML <DATALIST> has ghost values, even though the innerHTML is set to empty

Tags: javascript, html, datalist

I have an HTML `<DATALIST>` that depends on a second field on the page. The second field has an onchange method that builds a string of innerHTML using an SQL query and sets the innerHTML for the datalist.

```
document.all.MyDataList.innerHTML='<built string>’
```

It works. I get the right data in the data list.

But if the query finds no data and the built string is empty, I have a problem. I still see some options in the pull down list. They seem to be values that had previously been selected. I am trying to locate these ghost values.

Chrome Dev Tools shows me that the children of the datalist object has `length=0`. So where are the values being displayed coming from? How do I clear them?

Comment: Create [mre] to help us help you using  button <>  in editor to create snippet

Comment: My question said

I have an HTML [open angle bracket]DATALIST[close angle bracket] ... but the UI seems not to escape those.

Also to set the innerHTML
document.all.MyDataList.innerHTML='built string’

Comment: And I said show us.

Comment: My code is written in IRIS Data Platform. I guess most people won't be familiar with that. Which is why I didn't post my code. 

That technology is well established and in this case not the issue. I am not asking to debug my code on the server.

My question, is why when I set  innerHTML to '' it leaves ghost values in the pull down menu. Is there something other than the children that can be dispalyed?

Comment: Posting a minimal example would help us visualize the problem, rather than describing code in words.  I don't know the answer, but it sounds like maybe you need to trigger a change event with an empty string between queries.  It's possible you're not triggering onchange events in the browser when you think you are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)